# How to disable metrics in Spring-Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I use DropWizard to collect my own metrics for endpoints. I like my solution since I can add my own dimensions to it as I wish.

Apart from this Spring automatically collects and adds additional metric data to Dropwizard which I don't need. How to disable metrics in Spring-Boot to disable this?

I have found `MetricsDropwizardAutoConfiguration.class`, and `DropwizardMetricServices.class` but none seem to have a property or config to turn them off.

So my next thought was to turn off Spring-Boot-Actuator's metrics. I found these application.properties, while debugging, but these did not turn off the metric logging:

```
endpoints:
  metrics:
    enabled: false
management.endpoints.metrics.enabled: false
spring:
  metrics:
    export:
      enabled: false
```

**EDIT**

springBootVersion = '1.5.9.RELEASE'

Comment: what spring boot version you are using??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to disable the auto-configuration: `MetricsDropwizardAutoConfiguration.class` using
`@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MetricsDropwizardAutoConfiguration.class})`. This way I had to introduce my own MetricRegistry @Bean.

Answer (score 2):

For `1.5.9` these should work:

```
endpoints.enabled=false # Enable endpoints.
endpoints.actuator.enabled=false # Enable the endpoint.
```

This should work in 2.x:

**in application properties:**

```
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=false
```

in yaml:

```
management:
  endpoint:
    metrics:
      enabled: false
```

Comment: springBootVersion = '1.5.9.RELEASE'

Comment: Based on the docs in 1.5.9 

endpoints:
  metrics:
    enabled: false

should do the trick, but it does not

Comment: for 1.5.9 its  spring.metrics.export.enabled=false, are u using application.properties or yml??

Comment: try both as its given both: endpoints.enabled=false# Enable endpoints.
endpoints.actuator.enabled=false# Enable the endpoint.

Comment: But does these disable only the metrics or whole actuator?

Comment: In 1.5.9 it will disable all as seems per documentation but in later versions individual metrics can be also disabled

Comment: is there a way to dynamically disable these at runtime?

Comment: Das not work for Spring Boot 2.5.3 and Spring Cloud AWS 2.3.1